# Need to get C program name inside shell script

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have an occasion where a C program invokes a shell script, which in-turn does some copying stuff from the CD mount location to an installation directory.

Now my question is that, is there a straightforward approach to get the *absolute* path of this C program inside this shell script ?.

I tried a couple of approaches that includes using "$(ps -o comm= $PPID)" from within the script, but nothing did work out till now. I know that I can create a temporary file from the C program which contains its own name (argv[0]) and then make the shell script to read that file, but I don't want to follow that approach here.

Of course, it can be passed as an argument to the script, but I was thinking why the bash built-in macros or something cannot be used here

Comment: Why would you want to do something non-obvious, non-portable if there is an easy, off-the-shelf solution: pass the path as a parameter? Works with almost all shells in almost all operating systems. Or, perhaps, set an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

On linux there is a `/proc/self/exe` path that points the absolute path of the current executed file. So you can push an environment variable that contains the path before spawning the shell. Something like:

```
readlink("/proc/self/exe",...,buf);
putenv("MYEXE",buf);
system("thescript");
```

and accessing the variable in the script:

```
echo $MYEXE
```

Comment: But `/proc/self/exe` from a shell script is often a link to `/bin/bash`

Comment: No I mean using /proc/self/exe in the code before launching the script!

Comment: Then  `/proc/$PPID/exe` inside the script could be simpler.

Comment: What if the script spawns others?

Comment: Within that script, `$PPID` is still the parent process (that is the executable).

Comment: PPID is always the pid of the process that launched you, isn't it?

Comment: Nice approach !, but I was using the popen() for executing this script & the output was blank

Comment: `char *cmd = "sh script.sh";
char buf[BUFSIZ];
FILE *ptr, *file;
struct stat fs;
char envar[BUFSIZ];

file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (!file) abort();


readlink("/proc/self/exe",buf);
sprintf(envar,"MYEXE=%s",buf);
puts(buf);
putenv(buf);
printf("\nCalling script");

if ((ptr = popen(cmd, "r")) != NULL) {
   while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, ptr) != NULL)
   fprintf(file, "%s", buf);
   pclose(ptr);
   }
 fclose(file);`

Answer (score 0):

Before running a `foo` command you could use [which](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) like

```
fooprog=$(which foo)
```

to get the full path of the program (scanning your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)). For example `which ls` could give `/bin/ls` ....

On Linux specifically you could use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

In your shell [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) (running `bash` or some POSIX compliant shell) started by your C program, `$PPID` give the parent process id, hopefully the pid of the process running your C program.

Then the [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) is `/proc/$PPID/exe` which is a symbolic link. Try for example the 
 `ls -l /proc/$PPID/exe` command in some terminal.

<sup>(notice that you don't run C source files or stricto sensu C programs, you often run some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable which was built by compiling C code)</sup>

You might have weird cases (you'll often ignore them, but you might decide to handle them). Someone might *move* or *replace* or *remove* your executable while it is running. Or the parent process (your executable) died prematurely, so the shell process becomes [orphan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process). Or the executable removed itself.